# boost::variant for boost::arrays of arbitrary size

Tags: c++, arrays, boost

I'd like to create a `boost::variant` in the spirit of

```
typedef boost::variant<boost::array<int, 1>, boost::array<int, 2>, boost::array<int, 3>, ... > any_int_array;
```

generalized to `N` for the second value of the template.  In other words, a `boost::variant` that holds arrays of any size.  Is this possible?

Note that in the example above, `boost::array` is one of my cases, but it needs to be a viable solution for any class that takes a single `int` value as a template parameter.

Comment: Does `N` have a fixed maximum value? If not, this is not possible.

Comment: I can arbitrarily set the maximum at something like 1000, that's not a problem.

Comment: I don't envy the poor guy who has to write the static visitor for that. Why not just use a std::vector?

Comment: Your question asks whether such a thing is possible. You know it is. You just don't want to type all the hundreds or thousands of parameters you'd need to pass to the `variant` declaration. Is your question really *how* to define the type while keeping the code concise? Or was there something else about your goal that was giving you trouble?

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the question - how to define the type while keeping the code concise.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're talking about types with a statically known capacity, can't you dig your way out of this hole with some *template metapgrogramming*?

[Live on **Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0252a4790ae38767):

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

template <template <typename, size_t> class T, typename V, size_t N>
    void foo(T<V, N> const& something)
    {
        std::cout << __LINE__ << ": " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }

template <template <size_t> class T, size_t N>
    void foo(T<N> const& something)
    {
        std::cout << __LINE__ << ": " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }

int main()
{
    boost::array<int, 67> a;
    boost::array<double, 78> b;
    std::bitset<47> c;

    foo(a);
    foo(b);
    foo(c);
}
```

Printing

```
9: void foo(const T<V, N> &) [T = array, V = int, N = 67]
9: void foo(const T<V, N> &) [T = array, V = double, N = 78]
15: void foo(const T<N> &) [T = bitset, N = 47]
```

### Update

*Brainwave:* I just realized that `std::array<>` is *specified* to be a POD (trivial) type. As such, the layout **MUST** be standard, and the size **MUST** be identical to the equivalent `T[N]` array. Due to these restrictions, you can **safely** cast any `std::array<T, M>` to `std::array<T, N>&` (with matching *const/volatile* qualification) as long as `N>0` and `N<=M`.

Conversely, the storage required for

```
variant<array<T, 1>, array<T, 1>, array<T, 1>, .... array<T, 1000> >
```

will always be **at least** `sizeof array<T, 1000>` + overhead for the type discriminator (`which()`). There is no gain in making the distinction between all the other distinct array<> instantiations if only the dimensions vary

Comment: I just had a brainwave that you can use to simplify the situation, at least regarding the arrays. See **`Update`** _`Brainwave`_

Answer (score 2):

You can write this as follows:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/range_c.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector/vector0.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/size_t.hpp>

struct TransformToArray {
    template<typename N>
    struct apply {
        typedef boost::array<int, N::value> type;
    };
};

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
//As this value is increased, compilation time also increases (by a large amount)
const std::size_t MaxValue = 100;
typedef typename mpl::transform<
    mpl::range_c<std::size_t, 0, MaxValue>,
    TransformToArray,
    mpl::back_inserter<mpl::vector0<>>
>::type Arrays;


int main() {
    boost::make_variant_over<Arrays>::type variant;
}
```

(this could trivially be extended to other types by writing more `struct TransformToArray`-like functions).

This may not be useful, as the compile-times are absurd.

Comment: I just looked into this - I'm not sure if it works, as I'm having trouble setting the variant to an array.  It seems not to work in the same way a normal variant would.

Comment: @mikesol: Sorry, the variant should be constructed as `boost::make_variant_over<Arrays>::type`, rather than `boost::variant<Arrays>`.

Comment: Excellent! Now I just need some help understanding it :-) I thought that mpl transform took two sequences and a binary operator for its three arguments. I can see that range_c is a sequence, but how is TransformToArray a sequence and how is the back_inserter an operator?

Comment: I'm using the alternate form for `mpl::transform` in which the first argument is a sequence, the second argument is a unary operation, and the third argument is an [Inserter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/inserter.html). See the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/transform.html).

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use `boost::container::static_vector`.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.static_vector

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html

`static_vector` allocate from stack.

You can use `static_vector<T, 1000>` instead of `variant<array<T, 1>, array<T, 2>, array<T, 1>, .... array<T, 1000> >`.